# Estou fazendo uma inserção de imagem com jquery ajax e php mas o move_uploaded_file não está funcionando ele não envia nada

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

**HTML**

```
 <form id="formImage" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="corpo">
          <div class="foto">
            <h5 class="white-text title">Escolha sua foto de perfil</h5>
            <br>
            <div class="imagem">
                <label for="inputImagem"><img 
  src="https://cdt.org/files/2015/10/2015-10-06-FB-person.png" alt id="img_perf" 
 class="circle z-depth-2"></label>
                <input type="file" id="inputImagem" name="foto">
            </div>
            <br>
    </form>

            <br>
            <a class="btn cor_tema btn_proximo" id="prox1"><i class="material-icons">arrow_forward</i></a>
          </div>
```

**JS**

```js
$("#prox1").click(function(){

  var fd = new FormData();
  var files = $('#inputImagem')[0].files [0];
  fd.append ('foto', files);

  $.ajax({
    url:"http://localhost/servidor/insereImg.php",
    dataType:'json',
    type:'POST',
    data:fd,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success:function(r){
      if(r.Resp==1){
          localStorage.setItem("Foto","http://localhost/servidor/img/" + r.Foto);
        }
      },
    error:function(e){
        console.log(e);
      }

  })
});
```

**PHP**

```html
<?php

header('Content-type: application/json');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*');

if ($_FILES['foto']) {
          date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
          $data = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
          $extensao = substr($_FILES['foto']['name'],-4);
          $novoNome = md5($data).$extensao;
          $diretorio = '/http://localhost/servidor/img/';
          move_uploaded_file($_FILES['foto']['tmp_name'], $diretorio.$novoNome);
          $img = $novoNome;
        }

  $resposta = array('Resp' => '1',
                    'Foto' => $img
  );





ob_clean();
echo json_encode($resposta);
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No código `PHP`, há um erro no valor da variável `$diretorio`.

```
$diretorio = '/http://localhost/servidor/img/';
```

A mesma deverá ter o caminho completo de onde serão armazenados os arquivos do upload. Exemplo:

```
$diretorio = '/var/www/html/upload_de_imagens/';
```

**UPDATE:**
Em servidores windows, poderá utilizar:

```
$diretorio = 'c:\\xampp\\htdocs\\servidor\\img\\';
```

**Código PHP corrigido:**

```
<?php

header('Content-type: application/json');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*');

if ($_FILES['foto']) {
          var_dump($_FILES['foto']['name']); // testa se foi postado

          date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
          $data = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
          $extensao = substr($_FILES['foto']['name'],-4);
          $novoNome = md5($data).$extensao;

          // $diretorio = '/http://localhost/servidor/img/'; // incorreto
          $diretorio = 'c:\\xampp\\htdocs\\servidor\\img\\'; // correto

          move_uploaded_file($_FILES['foto']['tmp_name'], $diretorio.$novoNome);
          $img = $novoNome;
        }

  $resposta = array('Resp' => '1',
                    'Foto' => $img
  );





ob_clean();
echo json_encode($resposta);
 ?>
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: ainda não entendi como assim eu teria que colocar o caminha partindo da página do formulário ???

Comment: Seu servidor é windows ou linux? Em que pasta estão os códigos PHP? Exemplo: /var/www/html/ ou C:\wamp\www\

Comment: c:\xampp\htdocs\servidor\img\

Comment: Fiz uma atualização na resposta, testa agora me me diz se deu certo.

Comment: Cara vc me ajudou muito obrigado, mas agora eu gostaria de saber como eu faço para deixa-lo funcionando em um servidor web. o 000.webhost

Comment: @JottaVideos, caso tenha dado certo, peço que escolha a minha resposta e marque a mesma com +1. Para a nova questão, crie uma pergunta nova e te ajudo lá (só me enviar o link).